# I cant sculpt evenly with missing faces

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, sculpting, faces

There are missing faces in edit mode, but only on parts of the inside of the mesh and outside. For example, there may be no vertices or faces in black on the outside of the mesh in a specific area, but when I view the inside, they are there and vice versa. When I sculpt I have to move from one side to the other because it does not allow me to sculpt certain parts on each side.[image: edit mode][image][image]

Comment: Sounds as if the normals are inverted on parts of the mesh. Select All in Edit mode and then SHIFT-N to recalculate normals.

Comment: Please don't post photos of your screen! You can take screenshots from the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender then insert the image that is created directly inot your question. That eliminates any reflections and distortion that may be produced.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for your reply and I apologize, I did shift n to calulate normals and nothing happened until I checked the box next to “inside” in the bottom[image: editmode] left of the screen, and the results are what are shown in these screenshots. Do you also know how to fix that line going down his back? I cannot seem to sculpt over it.[image: sculptmode]